# remove title link in single page

Tags: php, wordpress

this is how i call the post title:

```
<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
```

i have not single.php in my theme:

```
<?php
    if (is_singular()) {<h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>};
    else {<h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>}
?>
```

but above code is not working, any idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's a syntax error. You probably want something like this instead.

```
<?php if (is_singular()) { ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php } else { ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php } ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

A good practice in cases like these is to put all your code on a new line rather than try to pack everything in a single line. This makes it easier to see a syntax error like forgetting to use '?>' as you did after the opening bracket of the if-statement.

```
<?php
if (is_singular()) 
{ ?>
    <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
<?php }
else 
{ ?>
    <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php }
?>
```

Though in your case it would really be better to not interrupt the coding like that all the time and just use echo to write the line.

```
<?php
if (is_singular()) 
{ 
    echo '<h2>'. the_title() .'</h2>';
}
else 
{
    echo '<h2><a href="'. the_permalink() .'">'. the_title() .'</a></h2>';
}
?>
```

Comment: I won't downvote this but the echo suggestion is extremely subjective. I find it annoying as to maintain and edit. Separating html and php is more clear to me (again, subjective)

Comment: You are right, but it seemed to me that at a beginners level it is an obvious thing to do. It at least shows him two ways to get it to work without crashing.

Comment: String concatenation seems more complicated to deal with.

Comment: `the_title()` does not return a string. It echoes something. Therefore `echo '<h2>' . the_title() . '</h2>'` will echo `title<h2></h2>`. Same with `the_permalink()` below.